# Xamarin Cross Platform Table with rows and columns

Tags: c#, xamarin

I want to make a simple table with rows and columns:

```
C1 C2 C3 C4

R1 R1 R1 R1

R2 R2 R2 R2
```

and so on.

At first i started to make a Grid and assign labels to columns and rows but is very hard to manage it and do stuff like, filter, rearrange and delete rows. What else can I do?

Edit:
To delete rows I used a Dictionary with a value representative for each row and the row number. After that I just used `layout.Children.RemoveAt(rowNumber)`. The problem is that  the other rows do not reposition and there are gaps between them. I think I will have to remake the layout for each row deletion.

Comment: Do you really need a table? Border and line? Or just arrange them in the order you showed?

Comment: i don't really need the border and line, just arrange. I managed to do something with stacklayouts horizontal oriented for rows. Now I want to see if it's an easy way to delete a row.

Comment: Maybe with just Children.Remove it could work out..

Comment: I need to see how I can uniquely identify each stacklayout so I can access it's children. Posted a question on xamarin forums. Hope they will answer

Comment: Well if you do `stack.Children.Add (mapLayout);` and to this stack will be assigned other Children, doing `stack.Children.Remove(mapLayout);` should identify the stacklayout uniquely.

Comment: Tell me if it works, i'll post an answer so it will help other users.

Comment: Hmm...The rows( horizontal stacklayouts) are added dynamically. Something like StackLayout newRow = new StackLayout{ ...properties...} and then stack.Children.Add(newRow). How will I identify each row?

Comment: I have another idea. What if I make a dictionary mapping each row's index with an identifier. And when I want to delete rows I just look for that identifier in the dictionary and just take the row index and with the Children.RemoveAt(index) I can remove it.

Comment: stack.Children return an IEnumerable, so you can iterate through it and select the row you want to eliminate if you know the row number that you want to remove. `stack.Children.GetEnumerator` should be what you need. Also being an IEnumerable you could use `Linq`

Comment: Sorry.. It's an IList, so doing `stack.Children[row];` should work too.

Comment: that was the problem that I do not know the row number because the data are coming from a DB. Now I am trying with the Dictionary.

Comment: Ok I managed  to remove a row, but the rest remain at their position. I may just have to rebuild the table with only the good rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it could be the easiest way, create a ViewItem and A ViewModel item, the view will be something like this:

```
public class NearMeView : ContentPage
    {
        private ListView _listView;
        private MyViewModel _viewModel;
        public NearMeView ()
        {
            _viewModel = new MyViewModel ();
            BindingContext = _viewModel;
            _listView = new ListView (){
                ItemTemplate = CreateItemTemplate ()//Here you will set th data templates for each row and in each label nameLabel.SetBinding<Item> (Label.TextProperty, x => x.Name);
            };
            _listView.SetBinding<MyViewModel> (ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, x => x.Rows);
}

public class MyViewModel : ViewModel
{
     List<Item>Rows;//will be populated from your DB each item will represent a Row, so you just need to remove from this list the item and automatically from the View should be removed the row.
    // Method that you need to remove filter etc.
}
private DataTemplate CreateItemTemplate ()
        {//this metod create the layout that you want to apply for each row in this example there are 3 columns, in each column there is a label, each label is binded to an element of the ItemSourceProperty of the ListView
            return new DataTemplate (() => {
                var nameLabel = new Label ();
                var typeLabel = new Label ();
                var distanceLabel = new Label (){   HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.EndAndExpand,VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center   };
                nameLabel.SetBinding<BranchModel> (Label.TextProperty, x => x.Name);
                typeLabel.SetBinding<BranchModel> (Label.TextProperty, x => x.Type);
                distanceLabel.SetBinding<BranchModel> (Label.TextProperty,x=> x.Distance);
                var leftStack = new StackLayout (){
                    Orientation = StackOrientation.Vertical,
                    VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.Center,
                    Children = { nameLabel, typeLabel },
                    Padding = new Thickness (8,0,0,0)

                };
                return new ViewCell () {
                    View = new StackLayout () {
                        Orientation = StackOrientation.Horizontal,
                        Spacing = 5,
                        Children = { leftStack, distanceLabel },
                        Padding = new Thickness (0,0,0,8)
                    }
                };
            });
        }
```

This is pretty much the code that I use to filter a list using a SearchBar

Comment: I get some errors. The BranchModel I suspect that is a model that you described. I don't know what is the _branchesListView and do not know exactly what to do in the CreateItemTemplare(). Just create new labels and assing them values? Don't I do that in the  CreateBranchItemTemplate?  And what is the element that I will bind to the ContentPage? The _listView?

Comment: And 1 question: a ListView displays the elements vertically. That means that I will make a horizontal StackLayout with my ListViews as the Columns. Correct? If it's so, I will construct my table via columns not rows witch is less logical, in my opinion.

Comment: [ListView](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/listview/) each row will contains some other layout, if one row contains 4 element they are your column.
Now I'll just correct the code

Comment: System.InvalidCastException: Cannot cast from source type to destination type.    I got this. It seems that a lot of people get this exception and xamarin did not fix it.

Comment: Where? btw instead of List<Item> Rows  here each item should contains what you want to have in your row... For this example an Item contains 3 property: Name,Type and Distance, these 3 will be my 3 column, so if I have a list of 2 Item, I will have:
ROW1:   `Frank    Person     35Km`
ROW2:   `Rex       Dog         44Km`

Comment: Yes I have modified there.  _listView.SetBinding<MyViewModel> (ListView.ItemsSourceProperty, x => x.Rows);  here it says that

Comment: Instead of `List<Item>` try `IEnumerable<Item>`

Comment: Did you inherit MyViewModel from VIewModel? You will find it here:
Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Mvvm

Comment: It appears I do not have that library Labs. I have the latest Xamarin download. Maybe it has been removed. A ViewModel must inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged as I read in the documentation

Comment: Yes but if you inherit from Labs.Mvvm you don't need it...This Library take care of it.

Comment: I have downloaded the package and added the reference. I see the reference in my project, but cannot use it. Do you have any idea of this? It's a version thing?

Comment: I have using Xamarin.Forms.Labs.Mvvm;  Then Labs is 1.2.0  Xamarin.Forms 1.3.2

Comment: i have forms 1.3.1.0 maybe that's why. Anyway, I got the idea and I understood the code. The rest will be left to me to fix the labs. Thank for the help :) Cheers